# SQL Query to Sum up the total marks of students and print 'Absent' instead of total marks if the marks field is null for all exams

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here the tables are

student : id,name,gender and dob
studentmarks : stId,subject,marks (This table will have multiple records for the same student i.e. marks of multiple subjects)

studentage : studentId,age

The columns id,stId and studentId are same (student id)

The question is to calculate and display the total marks along with id,name,gender and age for each student, if the student has marks for at least one subject. If the value of marks column is null/empty for all subjects, then 'Absent' should be printed for that student in the place of total marks.

The query I have tried is this, but somehow I feel this query isn't even remotely close to being sufficient to get the desired result

```
select s.id,name,gender,case marks is null then 'Absent' else sum(marks) end as total
from student s join studentmarks sm on s.id = sm.stId join
studentage sa on sa.studentid = s.id
```

I'm looking for something like (don't mind the list format. I didn't know how to add new line)

- 1 Mike Male 500
- 2 Sam Male Absent
- 3 Martha Female 400

Comment: It's good pragramming practice to _qualify_ all columns, at least when several tables are involved. (Like `s.id` instead of just `name`.)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Also, never store age. People become older every year, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date of birth instead.

Comment: [COALESCE(SUM(whatever). 'Absent')](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) might help. I can't tell enough about your data design from your question to offer more specific advice.